# Breadth-first search can't traverse index 0

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement the doBFS function, which performs a breadth-first search on a graph and returns an array of objects describing each vertex and it doesn't traverse the vertex 0. Here is the code:

```
var doBFS = function(graph, source) {
    var bfsInfo = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        bfsInfo[i] = {
            distance: null,
            predecessor: null };
    }

    bfsInfo[source].distance = 0;

    var queue = new Queue();
    queue.enqueue(source);

    // Traverse the graph
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        var deq = queue.dequeue();

        for(var j = 0; j < graph[source].length; j++){
            var el = graph[source][j];
            // println('from = ' + source);
            // println('to = ' + el);

            if (bfsInfo[el].distance === null){
                bfsInfo[el] = { 
                    distance: bfsInfo[source].distance+1, 
                    predecessor: source };
                source = el;
                queue.enqueue(source);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return bfsInfo;
};
```

The graph I am trying to traverse is:

```
var adjList = [
    [1],        //0
    [0, 4, 5],  //1
    [3, 4, 5],  //2
    [2, 6],     //3
    [1, 2],     //4
    [1, 2, 6],  //5
    [3, 5],     //6
    []          //7
    ];
```

I am trying to traverse from index 3 so I called the function by calling `doBFS(adjList, 3);`
Here is the output, I got

```
vertex 0: distance = null, predecessor = null
vertex 1: distance = 3, predecessor = 4
vertex 2: distance = 1, predecessor = 3
vertex 3: distance = 0, predecessor = null
vertex 4: distance = 2, predecessor = 2
vertex 5: distance = 4, predecessor = 1
vertex 6: distance = 5, predecessor = 5
vertex 7: distance = null, predecessor = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

- `var deq = queue.dequeue();`: This variable `deq` is never used elsewhere in your code. Instead your loop continues to work with `source`. Correct this by pulling the next item into `source`.
- `source = el;`: this is not how BFS is supposed to work. The source should remain unchanged while iterating its neighbors (`el`). So enqueue `el` without assigning it to `source`.

So the relevant part should be:

```
        source = queue.dequeue();

        for(var j = 0; j < graph[source].length; j++){
            var el = graph[source][j];
            if (bfsInfo[el].distance === null){
                bfsInfo[el] = { 
                    distance: bfsInfo[source].distance+1, 
                    predecessor: source 
                };
                queue.enqueue(el);
            }
        }
```

If your queue is correctly implemented, then this corrected code will give the distances from the given source:

```
[
  { "distance": 4,    "predecessor": 1    }, // 0
  { "distance": 3,    "predecessor": 4    }, // 1
  { "distance": 1,    "predecessor": 3    }, // 2
  { "distance": 0,    "predecessor": null }, // 3
  { "distance": 2,    "predecessor": 2    }, // 4
  { "distance": 2,    "predecessor": 2    }, // 5
  { "distance": 1,    "predecessor": 3    }, // 6
  { "distance": null, "predecessor": null }  // 7
]
```